# Como adicionar propriedade de navegação do IdentityUser ao modelo sem violar a Clean Architecture (C# / ASP.NET Core)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arquitetura-de-software, asp.net-identity

De acordo com os princípios da Clean Architecture (Arquitetura Limpa), é recomendável evitar qualquer tipo de dependência na camada Domain. No entanto, eu preciso aproveitar os recursos fornecidos pelo ASP.NET Core Identity, incluindo o uso da classe IdentityUser. O desafio surge ao tentar adicionar uma propriedade de navegação ao modelo do IdentityUser sem criar dependências diretas, conforme preconizado pela Clean Architecture. Vou ilustrar com um exemplo:

```cs
public class Todo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool Done { get; set; }
    // Aqui, idealmente, deveria ser uma referência para IdentityUser, mas não é possível devido à restrição de dependências na camada de Domain.
}
```

Neste cenário, surge a pergunta: como incluir uma propriedade de navegação no modelo Todo para o IdentityUser sem violar os princípios da Clean Architecture?